# delete button is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here in my book database i included both delete and edit button for each of the rows of the book table.When i click delete button it doesn't go to deleteajax.php i.e.it dosen't delete the row of book.Here i have created 2 files one for books.php and another deleteajax.php.In deletebookajax.php i have included ajax code and jquery script...can u please check where i have come across the error.
books.php

```
<?php
include('assets/page_header.php');
?>

<?php
//error_reporting(0);
include('db/db.php');




$str="select * from books";

$query1=mysql_query($str);
echo($query1);
$q=mysql_num_rows($query1);

//$query2=mysql_query("select status from bookrentalinfo where bookid=$bookid");
//echo $query2;
//$res=mysql_fetch_array($query2);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>BookID</th><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Publisher</th><th>numcopies</th><th>shelfno</th><th>status</th><th>Action</th></tr>";
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$rows['bookid']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['title']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['author']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['publisher']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['numcopies']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['shelfno']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$rows['status']."</td>";
echo "<td><button class='button1' value='delete' name='delete' onclick='delete()'>delete</button></td>";
echo "<td><a href='edit1form.php?book_id=".$rows['bookid']."'>Edit</a></td>";


//echo "<td><button type='button'>delete</button></td>";
/*if($res['status']=="BORROWED")
{
echo "Sorry You Can't Delete The Book";
}
else
{
echo "The Row Is Deleted";
}*/


echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

deletebookajax.php

```
    <?php
if(isset($_GET['book_id']))
{
    $bookid = $_GET['book_id'];
}
include('assets/page_header.php');
?>


<input type="hidden" name="bookid" value=<?php if(isset($bookid)) echo $bookid; ?>>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".button1").click(function(e){

    var bookid = $("#bbookid").val();
    var title = $("#btitle").val();
    var author = $("#bauthor").val();
    var publisher = $("#bpublisher").val();
    var numcopies = $("#bnumcopies").val();
    var shelfno= $("#bshelfno").val();
    var status = $("#BooksStatus").val();
    var dataString='bbookid='+bookid+'&btitle='+title+'&bauthor='+author+'&bpublisher='+publisher+'&bnumcopies='+numcopies+'&bshelfno='+shelfno+'&BooksStatus='+status;
    if(author==''||title==''||publisher==''||numcopies==''||shelfno==''||status=='')
        {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        }
        else
        {
        function delete()
        {
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "db/deletebookajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            alert("submitted"+result);
            $('#display').html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
        }
        }
        e.preventDefault(); 
        });
        });
        </script>




<?php
include('db.php');

//if(isset($_POST['bookid']))
//
//$bookid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bookid']);
$delete = "delete from books WHERE bookid=$bookid";

$query1=mysql_query($delete);
if($query1)
{
$q=mysql_query("select * from books");
$display="<table>";
$display.="<tr><th>BookID</th><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Publisher</th><th>numcopies</th><th>shelfno</th><th>status</th><th>Action</th></tr>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
$display.="<tr>";
$display.= "<td>".$row['bookid']."</td>";
$display.= "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
$display.= "<td>".$row['author']."</td>";
$display.= "<td>".$row['publisher']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$row['numcopies']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$row['shelfno']."</td>";
$display.="<td>".$row['status']."</td>";
$display.= "</tr>";
}
$display.="</table>";
}
else
{
$display.= "U can't delete The book";
//echo "nothing";
}
echo $display;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use event delegation.. see [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Why is js-function `delete` defined in ajax-file? How does code from `book.php` will be aware of this function?

Comment: never ever use msql_*

Comment: where is `.button1`?

Comment: why are you ajaxing to the same page?

Comment: dynamically aded @madalinivascu `echo "<td><button class='button1' `

Comment: @guradio it's not dynamically added

Comment: sir, ihave defined  delete function in books.php of the button to jump to the delete script of the deletebookajax.php

Comment: .button1 is becauz i used class="button1" in books.php

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define a function within the document ready function, it is never being called. You can either define it in the global scope, or simply call the `.ajax` method directly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".button1").click(function(e){

    var bookid = $("#bbookid").val();
    var title = $("#btitle").val();
    var author = $("#bauthor").val();
    var publisher = $("#bpublisher").val();
    var numcopies = $("#bnumcopies").val();
    var shelfno= $("#bshelfno").val();
    var status = $("#BooksStatus").val();
    var dataString='bbookid='+bookid+'&btitle='+title+'&bauthor='+author+'&bpublisher='+publisher+'&bnumcopies='+numcopies+'&bshelfno='+shelfno+'&BooksStatus='+status;
    if(author==''||title==''||publisher==''||numcopies==''||shelfno==''||status=='')
        {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        }
        else
        {
        //function delete()
        //{
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "db/deletebookajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            alert("submitted"+result);
            $('#display').html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
        //}
        }
        e.preventDefault(); 
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function out side of click event and call it something like this:

```
if(author==''||title==''||publisher==''||numcopies==''||shelfno==''||status==''){
    alert("Please Fill All Fields");
} else {
    delete();    
}


function delete() {
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "db/deletebookajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
    alert("submitted"+result);
    $('#display').html(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: okay then did you tried to put your code without function as shows snippet by @KAD ?

Comment: are your sure that your cursor is come into else condition when you click on button may be there are chance that going in if. It's better if you confirm once.

Comment: when i click button it dosent go for script even i use alert("hi") for simply

Comment: Put this code in directly else condition. And check alert error is come ? " $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "db/deletebookajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('error');
    }
});"